# Is const char* a string or a pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I thought const char* represents a mutable pointer to an immutable string.

However, when I do this,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char *name1 = "Alex";

int main() 
{
   name1 = "John";
   cout << name1 << endl;
}
```

it just prints John and shows no problems. I wonder why the program treats name1 as a string and makes it mutable?

Comment: It's a "string" in the "array of characters, zero terminated" sense, not in the `std::string` sense.  The pointer is mutable.  To make a const pointer, `const char * const name1 = "Alex";`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder why the program treats name1 as a string and makes it mutable?

It doesn't, you just assigned a new address to the pointer (the address of `"John"`). You said it yourself *"a **mutable pointer** to an immutable string"*. You modified the pointer, and had you tried to actually modify the pointee, the type system would have prevented you from doing that (on account of the const qualifier).

Comment: Actually, its a mutable pointer to an immutable character which is part of a character array located in the text part of your executable.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer and by assigning it to "John", you make it point to another case memory where "John" starts.

Answer (score 2):

- It is a pointer
- A pointer is an adress in memory.
- Here you reassign the adress of "John" to name1.
- cout knows how to print a char * so you see things correctly.

There are no string object in the program

Answer (score 2):

Just for illustration/comparison (in *addition* to the answers given already): the counter example...

```
const char *name1 = "Alex";

int main() 
{
    name1[0] = 'J';
    name1[1] = 'o';
    name1[2] = 'h';
    name1[3] = 'n';
    std::cout << name1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now you do *attempt* to really modify the immutable string. Luckily, the compiler detects it and prevents you from doing so! `const_cast<char>(name[x]) = y;` would be next attempt. Looks like fooling the compiler, actually, you fool yourself only by lying and in consequence running into **undefined behaviour**!

Actually, casting const away is almost always a bad idea (but is legal, if *and only if* the pointer holds the address of some originally non-`const`ly created memory).

Comment: I don't think the next attempt for everyone is to use `const_cast` :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Hm, do you think the subsequent sentence is not explicit enough?

Comment: I was just trying to be funny, I find it ok :)

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why the program treats name1 as a string and makes it mutable?

Heed the sequence of `const` in comparison to `*`. If you want to disallow a rebinding of `name1`, use `char * const`. See also [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Furthermore, `const` is not about a value being immutable, but about an immutable binding.